# Can't connect to the Internet using an Ethernet cable on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, 20.10

My Ethernet isn't working. Let's try and resolve that.

Alright so, I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu so I have nothing from apt-get installed (so no net-tools, etc.)

I have no other computers around me apart from my M1 MacBook Pro and (of course) my Ubuntu PC, running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Now, for some debugging, let's look at the outputs of some commands.

`nmcli device` says: `enp3s0 - ethernet - connecting (getting IP configuration)`.

`ip a`, this returns a long string and since I can't copy and paste from my Ubuntu Machine, I have to type it out manually so I'll only put what's important:

```
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000

  link/ether 1c:1b:0d:9f:da:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

  inet6 fe80::e279:831b:566e:595c/64 scope link noprefix router

    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`sudo lshw -C network`, sheesh, this is a long one. Please comment what important things you will need here as I don't want to include everything.

`lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` says:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [**0200**]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTl8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
   Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
   Kernal driver in use: r8169
   Kernal modules: r8169
```

I don't know what to do and have tried many solutions here at the Ask Ubuntu forums. I've changed like `managed=false` to `managed=true` somewhere and... well, my memory is trash so I don't know what else I've done.

:(

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly to provide more specific information about your issue.

Comment: What do you mean? At least give me some info on what's missing.

Comment: You seem unsure about the version of Ubuntu you’re running, and there is zero actionable information regarding the computer with the problem. We know more about your Mac than your Ubuntu machine. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo lspci` and `ip a` so that it might be feasible to offer specific suggestions 

Comment: Alright but I am on my Mac with Wi-Fi and on my Ubuntu PC without Wi-Fi so any long text, I have to type myself but ok.

Comment: Please tell me what important things I should put for the `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo lspci` details.

Comment: Please show us: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Comment: @chili555 Ok I have included that now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a bad file configuration in:

```
/etc/netplan/(filename).yaml
```

Look at this tutorial: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-networking-in-ubuntu-20-04-with-netplan/

Comment: Hey! Thanks new contributor, I have added a `/etc/netplan/ethernet.yaml` upon following a solution. I will look, thank you!

Comment: Ah I didn't add `dhcp4 = true` better try that!